# Ошибка pdo

Tags: pdo, php

```
$user = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FORM users WHERE name = ?",array("Michael"));

class DB{
private static $_instance = null;
private $_pdo, $_query, $_error = false, $_results, $_count = 0;

private function __construct(){
    try{
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.Config::get('mysql/host').';dbname='.Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch (PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public static function getInstance(){
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
        self::$_instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        }else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

public function action($action, $table, $where = array()){
    if(count($where) === 3){
        print_r($where);
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

        $field = $where[0];
        $operator = $where[1];
        $value = $where[2];

        if(in_array($operator, $operators)){
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

            if($this->query($sql, array($value))->error()){
                print_r($this);
                return $this;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function get($table, $where){
    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
}

public function delete($table, $where){
    return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
}

public function error(){
    return $this->_error;
}

public function count(){
    return $this->_count;
}
}
```

выводит такие ошибки

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FORM users WHERE name = 'Michael'' at line 1' in D:\Programs\OpenServer\domains\localhost\oop\classes\db.php on line 34
> ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FORM users WHERE name = 'Michael'' at line 1 in D:\Programs\OpenServer\domains\localhost\oop\classes\db.php on line 34

Comment: *right syntax to use near 'FORM users WHERE name = 'Michael''* убедитесь что правильный синтаксиз FORM - ну да, нужно FROM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@Xcho Xhurshudyan](/users/15227/xcho-xhurshudyan)](/users/15227/xcho-xhurshudyan) Что это такое?

```
"SELECT * FORM users WHERE name = ?",array("Michael")
```

Может надо так:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?",array("Michael")
```

На самой первой строке ошибка.